# cancel the scheduled android notification

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have scheduled android notifications using alarm manager but I couldn't cancel the notification where I tried to cancel it using this `notificationManager.cancelAll();` does not work and then I tried to cancel alarm manager itself, unfortunately, does not work.

Does anyone know how to cancel scheduled notification?

This is how I set alarm manager for notification:

```java
Intent myIntent = new Intent(DirctActivityfinal3.this, MyReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(DirctActivityfinal3.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeOff9.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

I  tried this code to cancel alarm manager, but not working I still get notified

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(ViewTicketActivity.this, DeleteNotification.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ViewTicketActivity.this,0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); 
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Why you tag me? :( I only edited the question to add syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 7):

Your PendingIntents are not the same.

To cancel an alarm, the pending intent that you created to cancel the alarm with must be the same as the one you created the alarm with.

e,g in your example, You are passing different classes into each.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(DirctActivityfinal3.this, MyReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(DirctActivityfinal3.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
```

is not the same as

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ViewTicketActivity.this, DeleteNotification.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ViewTicketActivity.this,0, intent, 0);
```

*Complete Sample:*

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(myContext, MyReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(myContext, 0, myIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
```

then either

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeOff9.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

or

```
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: how to cancel the scheduledJob from another activity for example: i have switch to disable notifications in settings page if disable it from settings page i have to cancel that scheduled job, how to do this?

Comment: Should we pass the same extras we passed when we created the alarm as well?

Answer (score -1):

Declare Intent, PendingIntent and AlarmManager as global variables

to cancel the scheduled

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ViewTicketActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```